# Creating Multiple Namespaces from the Kubernetes Command Line Interface

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to create multiple namespaces from the Kubernetes CLI (`kubectl`) without any YAML manifests:

```sh
kubectl create namespace app1,app2,app3
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl` expects exactly one namespace:

```
➜  / kubectl create ns
error: exactly one NAME is required, got 0
```

depending on your shell you could pack it into a loop. here's an example for bash and zsh:

```
➜  / foreach ns (ns1 ns2 ns3); kubectl create ns $ns; end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could chain together 2 kubectl commands like so:

```
kubectl create ns app1 && kubectl create ns app2...
```

Comment: is there more an elegant way

Comment: The command does not have such flags/options but @Markus' suggestion might be more fitting for you.